# Add File field in WooCommerce Box office plugin

Tags: plugin-development, customization, woocommerce-offtopic, custom-field

I'm using WooCommerce Box Office plugin and I want to customize this plugin according to my requirements for example I want to add another field option called 'file' so user can upload files as well while ordering product, I already add file type on the backend Here you can see:

[image]

And it's also showing on the frontend:

[image]

But the issue is when I submit the form it's indicate the error called "File is a required field and can not be empty." I already try to attached different file type but the error remains the same so can someone help me with that it's gonna be a very much appreciating.

[image]